# Apache PHP and Rails in subdirectory

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache

I need to setup rails in subdirectory with phusion passenger php being in root directory. I got it working but the rails static files are 404.
The apache config is below:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/folder_name/public/invite/*">
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home/folder_name/.gems
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppRoot /home/folder_name/public/invite
RailsEnv production
PassengerBaseURI /invite
</DirectoryMatch>
<DirectoryMatch   "^/home/folder_name/public/invite/public/*">
Allow from all
Options -MultiViews
# Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
#Require all granted
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DirectoryMatch but it takes a regular expression. which would look more like this:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/home/folder_name/public/invite/public/.*">
```